Named Instance to use port 1433 but ssms needs to include port 1433 for remote connection
I have a named instance installed  and have it set  to use TCP port 1433 instead of Dynamic ports. The SQL browser is running and TCP IP is enabled. I have to put the port number 1433 on ssms and without including the port number it wont connect. Please advice what am I missing here. Is this a firewall issue or am I missing something.


Please show your SSMS connection settings. Putting a named instance on the default port is rather strange and non-standard. Why don't you either use a different port or use a default instance?

Myservername\MyInstanceName,1433. If I use a different port for example 5755 what ports will I request my network team to open ?

Use either an instance name with SQL Browser service enabled, or a port number, not both. If you are using the default port then don't use either, just the machine name.

Myservername\MyInstanceName will not work but Myservername\MyInstanceName,1433 works and also Myservername works.

That's probably because SQL Browser is either off or blocked by the firewall. Like I said: 1433 is the default port so you don't need either name or port, and anyway if you specify a port the instance name is ignored.

So if I ask my network team to open UDP port 1434 will I be able to connect using Myservername\MyInstanceName.

Yes, and switch on SQL Browser service to Automatic Start. But I'd advise using a fixed port number if you can as it's faster to connect. Ie carry on using Myservername,portnumber instead of Myservername\InstanceName

If it's listening on 1433, which your screenshot shows, then the no port is needed and the machine name should be used.
Example, if the server is named MyServer and the SQL Instance is named MySQLInstance then the connection string for 1433 should be: MyServer.

I was able to connect as you said only using the machine name. I would like to connect using Myservername\MyInstanceName instead of Myservername\MyInstanceName,1433. Will that be possible ?

@SQL_NoExpert Why do you feel you need to do that? What's wrong with just the machine name if it's on the default port?

My previous installations with named instance were using dynamic ports and I was able to connect remotely using Myservername\MyInstanceName. The firewall was also turned off . Since I have set to use a static port of 1433 with firewall this is something new to me.
